# How to find phpcs current default standard

Tags: php, visual-studio, coding-style, phpcs

I want to know my current PHPCS standard in Visual Studio

e.g:

```
 {
     "phpcs.standard": "PSR2"
 }
```

how to set it is given in the documentation

> phpcs --config-set default_standard value

Comment: You might be looking for the command `phpcs --config-show`

Answer (score 4):

when you config

```
phpcs --config-set default_standard value
```

a message will show up like:

> Using config file:
> /home/yourpc/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

so, the configuration will be storage in:

```
/home/yourpc/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf
```

Comment: If you want to use the local `phpcs` instead of the global `phpcs`, run `vendor/bin/phpcs --confi-set` instead

Answer (score 3):

You can run `phpcs` with `-i` to print your installed standards:

```
~$ phpcs -i
The installed coding standards are PEAR, Zend, PSR2, MySource, Squiz, PSR1, PSR12, Universal, NormalizedArrays, PHPCS23Utils, PHPCSUtils, NoGetCurrentUser, VariableAnalysis, WordPress, WordPress-Extra, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Core, IsolatedTests, WordPress-Core, WordPress and WordPress-Docs
```

You can get information on where these standards are being pulled from, as well as which configuration file is in use by calling `phpcs` with the `--config-show` flag:

```
~$ phpcs --config-show
Using config file: /Users/pz/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

installed_paths: /Users/pz/.composer/vendor/phpcsstandards/phpcsextra,/Users/pz/.composer/vendor/phpcsstandards/phpcsutils,/Users/pz/.composer/vendor/sirbrillig/phpcs-no-get-current-user,/Users/pz/.composer/vendor/sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis,/Users/pz/.composer/vendor/wp-coding-standards/wpcs,/Users/pz/Code/wpcom/bin/metrics/shared/phpcs-coding-standards/IsolatedTests,/Users/pz/Code/wpcom/bin/metrics/shared/phpcs-coding-standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Core,/Users/pz/Code/wpcom/bin/metrics/shared/phpcs-coding-standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress,/Users/pz/Code/wpcom/bin/metrics/shared/phpcs-coding-standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Docs
```

It's worth mentioning that if you have a `phpcs.xml` file in your project `phpcs` will try to discover and use that by default. If you want to run it with a specific standard, you will use the `--standard` flag:

```
phpcs --standard=Pear <option filepath etc>
```

The [usage page](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage) on the repository is quite comprehensive.